# converting Font Awesome to camelCase (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons, font-awesome

I tried to change font Awesome icon syntax to camelCase (Reactjs)
here is the icon
fort-awesome (icon name)

and this is how I tried to change

**app.js**

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faFortAwesome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faFortAwesome);
```

**Component.js**

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

 <FontAwesomeIcon 
  icon="fortawesome" 
  color="#6DB65B"
  size="2x"
  />
```

this is the error I got.

*./src/App.js
20:12-25 '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons' does not contain an export named 'faFortAwesome'.*

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { faFortAwesome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

This line searches for the faFortAwesome function in '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'. You cannot change the name of this because then it will not find the right function name. If you want to change the name you can add something like the following.

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { oldName } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const faFortAwesome = oldName;

library.add(faFortAwesome);
```

Comment: I think [import { oldName as newName } from 'dest'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) should also work.

Comment: Yes this is much cleaner

Comment: hi @owmasch, I just call the name of the icon from font awesome library, but the way it works is you have to change the icon name to camalCase, besides I tried to change other fonts in the same method and it's just works fine but for this one <i class="fab fa-fort-awesome"></i> = faFortAwesome.  i can't figure out why it's gives me error. check out this link https://alligator.io/react/font-awesome/ .